# ¿Cómo ignorar columnas de texto de un fichero en C?

Tags: c

Estoy tratando de guardar la información de una fichero en un arreglo en C, pero tengo problemas ya que en el archivo vienen strings que no son de mi interés y quisiera saber si hay forma de ignorarlos, he hecho ejercicios parecidos pero dónde solo venian números en el fichero y los agregaba a una matriz de la siguiente forma:

```
FILE *fichero;
fichero = fopen("ejemplo.txt","r");
if (fichero == NULL)
{                           
  printf("\nNo se puede abrir el fichero.");  
    return -1;
}
fscanf(fichero, "%d", &largo);
int matriz[largo][largo];
while(1)
{                                      
  if (feof(fichero))
      break;
    for (int i = 0; i < largo; ++i)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < largo; ++j)
      {
        fscanf(fichero,"%d\n", &matriz[i][j]);
      }
    }
}
```

eso me servia para archivos donde me daban el largo y solo los números pero ahora tengo uno así:

```
row1 1 2 4 6
row1 3 2 3 7
row1 4 3 7 6 2
row2 2 3 5 6 4
row2 1 1 8
row2 5 3 4 4 4
row3 1 4 3 2 3 5
row3 6 1 7 
row3 7 1 9
```

Quisiera saber si hay una forma de ignorar la columnas de "rowX" para agregar solo los números a un arreglo

Comment: Si las líneas (aka registros) son variables, entonces ¿Cómo sabes cuantos datos leer por línea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo haber entendido tu problema, pero ..., en el archivo por en algunas líneas hay mas números que en otras, lo resolví reemplazando por ceros cuando no hay mas números dispibles en una línea.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int largo;
    FILE *fichero;
    fichero = fopen("ejemplo.txt","r");
    if(fichero == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nNo se puede abrir el fichero.");  
        return -1;
    }
    fscanf(fichero, "%d", &largo);
    char line[256];
    int  matriz[largo][largo];
    while(1)
    {
        if(feof(fichero))
            break;
        for(int i = 0; i < largo; ++i)
        {
            char* p = line;

            // Leer línea
            fgets(line, 256, fichero);

            // Saltear caracteres iniciales
            p += 5;

            for(int j = 0; j < largo; ++j)
            {
                int n;
                if(*p == '\0' || *p == '\n')
                {
                    // Si no hay mas dígitos, user el cero por default
                    n = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Transformar dígitos a entero
                    n = atoi(p);

                    // Salear dígitos
                    while(isdigit(*p))
                        p++;

                    // Saltear espacios
                    while(isspace(*p))
                        p++;
                }
                matriz[i][j] = n;
            }
        }
    }
}
```